# Corte fixo no KCFinder

Tags: kcfinder

No `kcfinder` quando você seleciona a imagem, ele mostra um corte na tela para você encaixar a foto.
Já procurei muito, fui no config em todos os arquivos e não descobri como alterar o `width` e o `height` deste corte.

Como faço para alterar estes tamanhos?